# Google Sheets Apps Script -- select value from cell with multiple lines

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is in GoogleSheets, using AppsScript.

Suppose I have a cell in A1 that contains the following value:

```
Dog Dog
Cat Cat Cat
Lion
```

I know I can select the entire contents of the cell using `.getValue()`, but how would I select just the fist line, `Dog Dog`, or just the second line, `Cat Cat Cat`? Each line may have multiple words associated to it, so I can't simply split by using the space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question.  You can still use `.getValue()` but you will need to add one more piece to break apart the value to the desired string.  `value.split("\n")[0];` will get the first linebreak listed.  If you want to get a different line then change `[0]` to another number.

```
function selectSingleLine() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tab = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var value = tab.getRange(1,1).getValue();  
  var firstBreak = value.split("\n")[0]; 
  var secondBreak = value.split("\n")[1];
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split by using char(10)

```
=split(A1,char(10))
```